# Proving the upper bound of the modulus of complex integration as follows.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $C$ be a contour with equation $z = 3e^{i \theta}, 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$. Show that
\begin{equation*}
\left|\int_C \frac{z^2}{z+1} \ dz \right| \le 27 \pi.
\end{equation*}

How to approach ? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You can just evaluate the left hand side   to be $2\pi$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using ML-inequality.
Notice that $|z| = 3$ and for all $z \in \Bbb C \setminus \{-1\}$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\left|\frac{z^2}{z+1} \right| \le 
\frac{|z|^2}{|z| - 1} \le
\frac{9}{2} = M.
\end{equation*}
We know that the length of the contour is $L = 3(2 \pi) = 6 \pi$.
Hence, by ML-inequality, we have
\begin{equation*}
\left|\int_C \frac{z^2}{z+1} \ dz \right| \le \frac92 \cdot 6\pi = 27\pi,
\end{equation*}
as desired. Q.E.D.